# need help in usps integration for my laravel project

Tags: mysql, laravel-8, e-commerce, usps

i have searched alot in internet and didnt find out any proper documentations for usps means they only provide few services like:

Rate Calculator (Both domestic and international)
Zip code lookup by address
City/State lookup by zip code
Verify address
Create Priority Shipping Labels
Create Open & Distribute Shipping Labels
Create International Shipping Labels (Express, Priority, First Class)
Service Delivery Calculator
Confirm Tracking

but how could i integrate but proper shipping using usps apis and the label printing and then tracking api for that shipments

Comment: Explain very extensively what you want to achieve. usps = US Postal Service. And you want to create shipping? Where? How? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: actually we are working with ecommerce store and they want to make shipment with ther orders, so we want to integrate it in it..

Answer (score -1):

You can access to USPS developer portal and reading their API document.Try to understand the function and then go to integrate it into your system https://developer.usps.com/getting-started